# Does testptp.c compile for anyone else?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile a script that helps me test LinuxPTP. The testptp.c file is a script that helps do this. It is built into the Linux kernel. However, I am unable to compile it. Is this just me? I see tons of people talking about this utility script but the only tutorials online I see are this: https://docs.nvidia.com/networking/display/NVIDIA5TTechnologyUserManualv10/Testptp

It tells you to compile testptp.c using gcc. I compiled using the following command, in a directory with just testptp.c: `gcc testptp.c -o testptp`. I also pulled the Linux kernel from git and went into `tools/testing/selftests/ptp` and ran `make`. Both yielded the same results.

Here is my output:

```
Makefile:10: warning: overriding recipe for target 'clean'
../lib.mk:130: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'clean'
gcc -I../../../../usr/include/    testptp.c  -lrt -o testptp
testptp.c: In function ‘main’:
testptp.c:295:15: error: ‘struct ptp_clock_caps’ has no member named ‘adjust_phase’
  295 |           caps.adjust_phase);
      |               ^
testptp.c:429:28: error: ‘PTP_PEROUT_DUTY_CYCLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  429 |    perout_request.flags |= PTP_PEROUT_DUTY_CYCLE;
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
testptp.c:429:28: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
testptp.c:430:18: error: ‘struct ptp_perout_request’ has no member named ‘on’
  430 |    perout_request.on.sec = pulsewidth / NSEC_PER_SEC;
      |                  ^
testptp.c:431:18: error: ‘struct ptp_perout_request’ has no member named ‘on’
  431 |    perout_request.on.nsec = pulsewidth % NSEC_PER_SEC;
      |                  ^
testptp.c:434:28: error: ‘PTP_PEROUT_PHASE’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘PTP_PEROUT_REQUEST’?
  434 |    perout_request.flags |= PTP_PEROUT_PHASE;
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            PTP_PEROUT_REQUEST
testptp.c:435:18: error: ‘struct ptp_perout_request’ has no member named ‘phase’
  435 |    perout_request.phase.sec = perout_phase / NSEC_PER_SEC;
      |                  ^
testptp.c:436:18: error: ‘struct ptp_perout_request’ has no member named ‘phase’
  436 |    perout_request.phase.nsec = perout_phase % NSEC_PER_SEC;
      |                  ^
make: *** [<builtin>: testptp] Error 1
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. Linux Kernel Version: 5.15.0-53-generic

Does this work for anyone else?

Comment: You also need to tell us which kernel this refers to and if this is the running version. It certainly compiles here on opensuse 5.14.21-24.33

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the file `/usr/include/linux/ptp_clock.h` with [the following file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/ptp_clock.h) seems to work for me.